# Create windows 2003 shortcut or MKLINK based on current date?

Tags: windows, symlink, shortcut, mklink

I need to create a symlink/shortcut on the prod servers that will alias:

```
agent_ivr_general_info.CURRENT
```

to

```
agent_ivr_general_info.[todays date].log
```

because I have daily rolling logs cush as:

```
agent_ivr_general_info.2011-04-28.log
```

That I want to just open 1 LINK to get to CURRENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I suppose one technique would be to use [Sysinternals' JUNCTION.EXE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) with a Scheduled Task that runs daily just after midnight, and uses something like the following to change the link:

```
cd TARGET_DIRECTORY
:: get date -- this only works for default US date, YMMV
set day=%DATE:~7,2%
set month=%DATE:~4,2%
set year=%DATE:~-4%
:: set %today% formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
set today=%year%-%month%-%day%
:: delete old link
junction -d CURRENT
:: create new one
junction -c CURRENT .\%today%
```